# Trying to change image resource on touch then change back on release

Tags: java, android

I'm changing the drawable resource when the user touches the imageview, and when they release it goes back to the default. I copied some code online which should work, but isn't. I commented in the errors I'm getting

```
final ImageView green = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Green);
green.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { //cannot resolve symbol setOnTouch...
                          //^^Invalid method declaration return type required
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) { //cannot resolve symbol view/event
        switch (event.getAction()) { //cannot resolve symbol event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { //constant expression required
                green.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_square);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { //constant expression required
                green.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank_square);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false; // cannot return a value of type void
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use a selector here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your selector as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/green_square"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/blank_square"/>
</selector>
```

And in your layout xml, set src as above selector.

Comment: I did but it's not doing anything

Comment: I had to change android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 0):

As a first guess, I think you are missing the import statements to go with that code.

Eg:

```
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
```

Comment: Nothing changed